# Invalid syntax when accessing class.lambda

Tags: python, class

I have a class defined as

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        return None
    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return self.__dict__[name]
```

when I set a class variable, for example

```
nm = test()
nm.alpha = 1
```

it gives me no issues, however when I do the following

```
nm.lambda = 1
```

I end up with `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I have a clue that lambda is a reserved keyword but is there a way to get around it? For now I have been using `nm.__dict__['lambda'] = 1` instead.

Comment: No, you cannot use a keyword as an attribute name. Just use something like `.lambda_`. Also, what is the point of your `test` class, why are you implementing `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` in this fashion?

Comment: The actual class is to handle fortran namelist files [code here](https://github.com/navdeeprana/namelists). A namelist file contains values of different variables which can be passed at runtime. Most of the physics variables have greek names, that's how lambda comes up as attribute name.